# Guessing game in C, cannot get the number of tries to work, variable is "counter"

Tags: c

Not too sure how to make the counter variable work to count how many tries it takes to guess the number right. Ive tried putting "counter++;" in each if statement but that doesn't do anything. This is my first code that I've written by myself so don't drag it too hard please <3

```
int main()
int counter
{
    int num , guess;
    counter = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    num = rand() % 200 + 1;

    printf ( "Guessing game, guess the number between 1 and 200" );

    do {
        scanf ( "%d" , &guess);
        if ( guess > num ){
        printf ( "Too high" );
    }

        if ( guess < num ){
        printf ( "Too low" );
    }

        if ( guess == num ){
        counter++;
        printf ( "Your guess is correct!, it took you %d tries" , counter );
        }


    }while (guess != num);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is `int counter` supposed to be `int main()`? You might want to fix up the code.

Comment: The counter should be incremented with each iteration (not just when `guess == num`).

Comment: Increment `counter` after each `scanf()` instead of only if `guess==num`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. When you have a problem you want help with, please also read [ask] and prodive a [mcve] if applicable. In your question, I see three problems. The first is that the error description isn't clear, make sure you mention observable facts ("prints 42") and not just interpretations ("doesn't work"). Further, reduce your code as much as possible so that it still compiles (the above doesn't!) and format it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You only increment `counter` when the user guesses correctly. You should instead increment it for every try.

There are syntax errors in your program.  Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    int num, guess;

    srand(time(0));
    num = rand() % 200 + 1;

    printf("Guessing game, guess the number between 1 and 200");

    while (scanf("%d", &guess) == 1) {
        counter++;
        if (guess > num) {
            printf("Too high\n");
        }
        if (guess < num) {
            printf("Too low\n");
        }
        if (guess == num) {
            printf("Your guess is correct! it took you %d tries\n", counter);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    return 1;
}
```